# Store variable of type ‘double’ in database as ‘DECFLOAT’

Tags: c++, sql, database

I have a database table in which data type of one of the field is DECFLOAT.
I am using db2 library V10.1 to store data in database using c++ (unixODBC). Is there support for DECFLOAT? 
If so what is the C representation for DECFLOAT and the header file to be used? 
If there is no support for DECFLOAT, how can I convert a ‘double’ value to ‘DECFLOAT’ while storing?

Your help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The C data types, SQLDECIMAL64 and SQLDECIMAL128, have been added for storing decimal float

values. A wide range of conversions are supported for the types. A new connection setting

named SQL_ATTR_DECFLOAT_ROUNDING_MODE allows the client to specify what type of rounding

should occur if any operations on the server side require rounding of a decimal float value.

you can try using sqlcli.h

Please check below link for more details:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.rn.doc/doc/c0022997.htm

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0000527.html

hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks. I will check this and get back to you.

Comment: Tried to set SQL_ATTR_DECFLOAT_ROUNDING_MODE from code but it is not working.

Comment: Can you tell me to store SQLDECIMAL64/128 which data type in c/c++ is to be used? Also how can I assign value to SQLDECIMAL64/128 as it is a union.